# How to use the command "range" in order to specify multiple cells for calculations

Tags: excel, vba, loops, average, calculation

The aim is to calculate the average and write it into a cell. The code for it is as following:

```
Sub Schaltfläche2_Klicken()     Dim wb As Workbook, wq As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet, datdatum

 Set wb = Workbooks.Add
 Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

 ws.Range("D84").Formula = "=Average(D19,D29,D35,D46)
 ws.Range("E84").Formula = "=Average(E19,E29,E35,E46)
 ws.Range("F84").Formula = "=Average(F19,F29,F35,F46)
```

The short way is:

```
ws.Range("D84:P84").Formula = "=Average(D19,D29,D35,D46)
```

And that works for the specified range.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and be sure to ask a [good, clear, concise question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion),  include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: please include all your code, with the expected result, and show us where it's going wrong - then we can try to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a loop. VBA will make the change on it's own:

```
s.Range("D84:P84").Formula = "=Average(D19,D29,D35,D46)"
```

Excel will change the column reference as if it were dragged across.

But if you really want to loop then you need to remove the vba from the quotes in the string and concatenate with `&`

```
 For i = 4 To 16
     ws.Cells(84, i).Formula = "=Average(" & ws.Cells(19,i).Address & "," & _
          ws.Cells(29,i).Address & "," &ws.Cells(35,i).Address & "," & _
          ws.Cells(46,i).Address)"
 Next i
```